# Extracting Ethereum Wallet "extract without encryption"

Tags: mist, wallets

When I download the wallet and extract the files, I get an alert that indicates that I am extracting the files "without encryption"

Is this normal?

Also, my security software won't allow the program to run.

Is that normal?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is telling you that error message? What operating system are you using?